# Why doesn't React component doesn't render even though webpack doesn't throw any errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

**app-client.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var APP = require('./components/APP');
React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

**App.js** (component)
    var React = require('react');

```
var APP = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (<h1>Hello World form React</h1>);
  }
});

module.exports = APP;
```

**webpack.config.js** I had issues with webpack but solved that with presets added. It runs fine now.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app-client.js", 
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            exclude: /(node_modules|app-server.js)/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: [
                    'es2015',
                    'react'
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

Index.html:

```
<div id="react-container" class="container">
    <h1>Live Polling</h1>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

**Folder structure**:

```
app-client.js
app-server.js
components
  - app.js
public
  - bundle.js
  - index.html
  - style.css
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

I run webpack, then start up the server but the contents inside the div "react-container" don't get overwritten with those of the component (app.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React `render` function was moved from `React` module to `ReactDOM` so please try this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom').
var APP = require('./components/APP');
ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Comment: This would likely work, however, looks like there are issues with the components. I'm getting this error now:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/Users/Michael/Desktop/interactivepoll'
 @ ./app-client.js 4:15-35`

Comment: This beacuse you don't have this module installed. To install this module using npm use this: `npm install react-dom --save`